# Doing Something Wrong with QSort?

Tags: c

I'm trying to sort a few different arrays of ints using qsort, but it doesn't seem to be performing the sort. Here are my comparator functions, one for sorting forward and one for backward:

```
int comp(const void *elem1, const void *elem2){
    int x = *(int*)elem1;
    int y = *(int*)elem2;
    if(x > y) return 1;
    if (x < y ) return -1;
    return 0;
}

int compReverse(const void *elem1, const void *elem2) {
    int x = *(int*)elem1;
    int y = *(int*)elem2;
    if (x > y) return -1;
    if (x < y) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is where I call qsort. The items to be sorted are malloc'ed int *s. NELEMS is a #define that divides the total byte size of the array with the size of an int to get the array length.

```
qsort(ascendingOrderArray, NELEMS(ascendingOrderArray),
            sizeof(*ascendingOrderArray),comp);
    qsort(descendingOrderArray, NELEMS(descendingOrderArray),
            sizeof(*descendingOrderArray), compReverse);
```

When I iterate through the new arrays, they are not in the order I would expect. In fact, they are in no order at all and indistinguishable from the unsorted array except for the placement of the first number. What's going on?

Comment: Comparison functions are not sufficient for sort implementation. Why did you ommit other stuff, I guess it will provide usefull information

Comment: Your `NELEMS` macro is almost certainly not correct. Are you trying to use `sizeof()` with a malloc'ed pointer? Please show more more code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say that `ascendingOrderArray` is allocated via `malloc()`, so the definition must be:

```
int *ascendingOrderArray;
```

But then you say `NELEMS()` is defined that divides the size of the array with the size of an int, so I assume the definition is something along the lines of:

```
#define NELEMS(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(int))
```

If that is the case, then the code isn't doing what you think it's doing.  Here, `sizeof(ascendingOrderArray)` is the size, in char units [1], of a *pointer* (on a 32-bit system the value will most likely be 4; on a 64-bit system, 8).  It is then being divided by the size of an integer (32-bit system most likely 4; 64 bit system it could be 4, could be 8---it depends on the compiler).  I would not be surprised if `NELEMS()` is returning the value of 1, which doesn't give `qsort()` a lot to work with.

What you need to do is call `qsort()` like:

```
qsort(ascendingOrderArray,itemsInArray,sizeof(int),comp);
```

where `itemsInArray` is a separate count of the number of elements in the allocated array.

[1] In C, `sizeof()` returns the size of the type relative to the size of a char; `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.  On most modern systems this is also a byte, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: I see... so does this mean that there is way to determine the size of a malloc'd array without keeping track of the number of items in the array through a separate value?

Comment: @user1427661: The short answer is __no__. There may be a non-portable method provided by your specific compiler or library but it's not part of the `C` language.

Comment: Sean, regarding your footnote, in C, a byte is defined to be the amount of storage a `char` occupies. What a byte (as C understands it) usually also is, but need not be, is an _octet_ [which is what outside C is usually also called a byte]. So when talking about bytes in the context of C, one must be careful. Terminology-nitpicking aside, well explained, +1.